# Embedded script not working with Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular

My name is Kris Chery. I am new with angular and am loving it so far. I am trying to add an SEO audit tool on my website but I cant seem to get it work. Even with some of the approach I found on this site. So here it is

The problem: embedding this script in to an angular view. **It works fine when you run the snippet below but not on my website**

```html
<center><div id="roboaudit"></div></center> <script  id="growthrobo" src="https://d3ikwiixxizqwk.cloudfront.net/assets/site/js/sitecheck.js" data-content="2080"></script>
```

Here is the code that I am trying

**home.component.ts**

```html
  
  import { BrowserModule, Meta, Title, TransferState, DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';


  leadGenerator: any ;

  constructor(
               private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
              ) {

                this.leadGenerator = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<center><div id="roboaudit"></div></center> <script  id="growthrobo" src="https://d3ikwiixxizqwk.cloudfront.net/assets/site/js/sitecheck.js" data-content="2080"></script>')
              }
```

**home.component.html**

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-12" [innerHtml]="leadGenerator">
          <h1 class="text-center"> Yo </h1>

      </div>
  </div>
```

Here is a link to the stackblitz

https://angular-hu9bip.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in your index.html file. Don't try and put it in a component. Just paste the html you are trying to inject straight into the index.html outside of the Angular app.

Make it look like

```
<my-app>
  loading
</my-app>
<center><div id="roboaudit"></div></center> <script  id="growthrobo" src="https://d3ikwiixxizqwk.cloudfront.net/assets/site/js/sitecheck.js" data-content="2080"></script>
```

Comment: Edit your index.html file and put the html directly into the html file, don't try and inject it with bypassSecurityTrustHtml

Comment: It works; So now how do i go about putting it in different pages; it renders at the bottom of my app?

Comment: Angular is a single page app

Comment: Yeah; I am using SEO pre render which forces the app to act like a href ref for better SEO. I just wanna be able to add it in section of each page instead of having it show up below the footer